# How to set id at runtime inside innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am new to JavaScript and HTML. I may ask a simple question but this also true that I am confused to find to find the solution.

I have alert box. at `onload()`,it asks for the number of rows to be appear as a list. Once
the number is entered, then the rows are populated as per demand of user in alertbox.

**My question is:** How to set the id here inside `innerHTML`, so that I can check out which item have been selected here.

It will also be useful, if any tutorial related to this is given.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scrollbar.css">

<script type="application/javascript" src="iscroll.js?v4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var myScroll;
function loaded() {
    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { scrollbarClass: 'myScrollbar' });
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);

</script>
        <!--    html,body {
                height: 50%
            }

            #left {
                float: left;
                width: 25%;
                height: 90%
            }
            #lst {
                width: 75%;
                height: 90%
            } -->
<style type="text/css" media="all">
body,ul,li {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
}

body {
    font-size:12px;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
    font-family:helvetica;
}

#wrapper {
    position:absolute; z-index:1;
    top:45px; bottom:48px; left:0;
    width:100%;
    background:#aaa;
    overflow:auto;
}

#scroller {
    position:relative;
/*  -webkit-touch-callout:none;*/
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);

    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
}

#scroller ul {
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
}

#scroller li {
    padding:0 10px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    background-color:#fafafa;
    font-size:14px;
}

#scroller li > a {
    display:block;
}

        </style>
<script type = "text/javascript">

function listClicked(id)
    {
        var listid = id;
        //alert("click called  "+ listid);
        if(listid == 'l1')
        {
            //alert("inside l1");
             window.document.location.href = 'l1.html';         
        }
        else if(listid == 'l2')
        {
            window.document.location.href = 'l2.html';  
        }
        else if(listid =='l3')
        {
            alert("Current date is:  "+new Date());
        }
        else if(listid == 'l4')
        {
            window.document.location.href = 'login.html';           
        }
        else if(listid == 'l5')
        {
            window.document.location.href = 'customList.html'
        }
        
    }
    
    function callAlert()
    {
        listRows = prompt("how many list row you want??");
        var ids = 0;
        var listText = "List Number";
                for(var i = 0;i < listRows; i++)
                {
                    if(i%2==0)
                    {
                    ids++;
                        listText = listText + "<p style ='background-color:#EEEEEE'>";
                    }
                    
                    else
                    {
                    ids++;
                        listText = listText + "<p>";
                    }                                   
                    listText = listText + i;
                    
                    document.getElementById("lst").innerHTML = listText+i;                  
                }
                //document.getElementById("lst").innerHTML = listText+i;
    }
            /*  if you name your html files lise so:

            htmlfile1.html
            htmlfile2.html
            htmlfile3.html

            then you can create a script that creates the filepath according to the value of the variable.


            <script type=text/javascript>
            var yourvar='???';
            window.location="htmlfile"+yourvar+".html"; */
            //-->
</script>
<body onload = callAlert();loaded()>
<ul style="list-style: none; margin-top:100px;">
<li id = "l1" onclick = listClicked(id);>list item 1</li>
<li id = "l2" onclick = listClicked(id);>list item 2</li>
<li id = "l3" onclick = listClicked(id);>Show current date alert</li>
<li id = "l4" onclick = listClicked(id);>Login</li>
<li id = "l5" onclick = listClicked(id);>list item 5</li>

    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">
    <ul id="thelist">
    <div id = "lst" ></div>         
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</ul>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Please help me find out the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
listText = listText + '<p style="background-color:#EEEEEE" id="foo' + i + '">';
```

so that each paragraph has a unique id. I prefer to use single quotes for script strings and double quotes for HTML attribute values.

Comment: @Steve . Thanks for your response mate. I got some more idea of improving the code.

Comment: @nick - you're welcome.  Next time maybe think about just putting the one line you want to fix, not the whole code ;)

Comment: @RobG Can you please let me know how do i get the value of the id in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To SET the ID, just use the ID property of a DOM element:

```
MyElement.id = "whatever";
```

But it looks like you want to GET the ID, like in this line:

```
onclick = listClicked(id);
```

In that case, you can just pass `this`, which will pass a reference that element, and use the ID property from that.

```
onclick = listClicked(this);
```

Javascript:

```
function listClicked (someElement) {
    alert(someElement.id);
}
```

---

The `listClicked` function in your code could use a few more improvements, too, something like:

```
function listClicked(element) {
    var listid = element.id;

    switch (listid) {
        case 'l1':
            alert("Foo");
            break;
        case 'l2':
            alert("Bar");
            break;
        default:
            alert("Default");
    }
}
```

Comment: please tell in detail.should i use this in the loop itself

Comment: @nick - updated. Just pass `this` to the function, and use `.id` to get the id of that element.

Comment: No,I dont want to get the id. I want to set the id in the innerHTML. see the function callalert()-for loop. there i am using the document  document.getElementById("lst").innerHTML = listText+i; Like this i want to set the id also. So that when any list item will be selected then i will get notification of that. Please saything related to this mate.

Comment: I think I addressed your question in my answer. You can set and get an id using the `.id` property.  `innerHTML` is a completely different thing.  If you mean the HTML that is already in the browser, that can't be changed.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Insert rows dynamically?

Comment: the inserting of rows is already setting.I want to insert the id to each row

Comment: Can you please tell me that how to access the value of the id in this case. coz here i have 1 id for <p> in body tag and one for each row of inner html.I have tried from both,but unable to find the specific solution of that